# Installed Eclipse "ADT" bundle for Android development - now auto assist doesn't work

Tags: eclipse

In installed the ADT bundle over my original Eclipse install ( Eclipse IDE for Java Developers, from http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) so that I could make use of LibGDX.

Now auto assist/complete will not work.

here are my settings...

[image]

You can see that class `ball.` doesn't pop up a suggested methods screen...

[image]

Any thoughts? I've tried restoring the defaults too

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Preferences - Java - Editor - Content Assist - Advanced - Restore Defaults

**EDIT:**

If others are having problem even after doing the above suggestion, please also check "Java proposals" is ticked/checked under - Preferences - Java - Editor - Content Assist - Advanced.

Comment: Also the Advanced option?